# GtkStatusIcon label in Gnome3

Tags: c, linux, icons, gnome, tray

How can affect on my app's status icon label in Gnome3? When i moving cursor on it shows me my app's executable name. How can I change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was `gtk_status_icon_set_title`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [gtk_status_icon_set_tooltip_text()](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.2/GtkStatusIcon.html#gtk-status-icon-set-tooltip-text) or [gtk_status_icon_set_tooltip_markup()](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.2/GtkStatusIcon.html#gtk-status-icon-set-tooltip-markup).

Alternatively, you can handle the [query-tooltip](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.2/GtkStatusIcon.html#GtkStatusIcon-query-tooltip) signal and set the text dynamically when the tooltip is shown.